# Smooth Ground Physics

Tags: java, collision-detection, physics

I've been working on some things in Java with Processing libraries, mainly things like a ball collider:

```
class Ball {

  PVector pos;
  PVector vel;
  PVector acc;

  int r;
  float mass=1.0;

  public Ball(PVector pos, PVector vel, int r) {
    this.pos = pos;
    this.vel = vel;
    this.acc = new PVector(0,0);
    this.r = r;
  }

  public void applyForce(PVector force) {
    this.acc.x = force.x/mass;
    this.acc.y = -force.y/mass;
  }

  public void onHit() {
  }

  public void update() {
    this.pos.x += this.vel.x;
    this.pos.y += this.vel.y;
    this.vel.x += this.acc.x;
    this.vel.y += this.acc.y;
    this.acc.x = 0;
    this.acc.y = 0;

    if(this.pos.x + .7*this.r > width || this.pos.x - .7*this.r < 0) {
      this.vel.x = - this.vel.x;
    }
    if(this.pos.y + .7*this.r > height || this.pos.y - .7*this.r < 0) {
      this.applyForce(new PVector(0,1.894));
    }

    if(abs(this.vel.y) < .79) {
      this.vel.y = 0;
    }
  }

  public void show() {
    fill(255);
    ellipse(this.pos.x,this.pos.y,this.r,this.r);
  }

}

Ball b;

void setup() {
  size(800,600);


  b = new Ball(new PVector(width/2,height/2), new PVector(3,1), 20);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);

  b.applyForce(new PVector(0,-1));
  b.update();
  b.show();
}
```

My problem is collisions. I try to make everything modelled by true physics, so I feel like collisions should be the same in any case (ball against ball, ball on ground, ball against a wall, etc.). But I've tried over and over to implement hit boxes and even just conditional collisions as above, but I cant get everything to work right. Is there an easy way to do something like this, or is it more conditional and generally case by case? And if it is the latter, where can I find an example of a simple ground-object interaction (or the likes)?

Comment: Just collision detection? Or are you looking for resolution as well?

Comment: Detection is pretty easy in this case, resolution is the part I'm stuck on.

Comment: Resolution is no trivial task. In order to handle all "cases" you'll need to use rigid body dynamics. Check out something like [Bullet Physics](http://bulletphysics.org/wordpress/).

Comment: Also checkout Separating Axis Theorem (SAT), it's an algorithm to find the collision resolution vector. You will also need something else to compute the bouncing.